# Maintaining a development database with exactly the same schema

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to run a different database for development as my initial product release is coming so I'd like to know how to maintain two different databases. I'm using postgresql as my DBMS

I want development database and production database to have exactly the same schema. Is there a way to do this automatically? If I have to to manually, what would be the best way to update schema?

thank you

Comment: Check out tools like Liquibase or Flyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want development database and production database to have exactly the same schema.

Then just create 2 databases with the same schema(s).

Or you can read more about template databases - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/manage-ag-templatedbs.html.

The idea is that when you create new database, it's actually copied from `template1`, thereof you can edit `template1`, and every new database will have schemas/tables that you need.